# Proof for this answer

Tags: relational-theory

I am not sure whether this is offtopic. However, please read on.

A person whom I know has encountered a problem in the answer key published by CBSE, India. As their key challenging form contains a column for citation/proof, we have to find some authentic book which can be shown as the base of our claim.

I attach the question here, and I request you to verify the answer and suggest us some book/other ways to prove our challenge (She has checked the regular syllabus books, but didn't find something precise related to this problem).

Question:

Identify the minimal key for relational scheme R(A, B, C, D, E) with
functional dependencies F = {A->B, B->C, AC->D}

The options are A, AE, BE, and CE

The key shows the answer is A and she says it is AE actually.

Please help us find some proof/way to challenge the key.

Answer (score 6):

The key is actually `AE`. The proof is simple, a key for definition is a minimal set of attributes whose closure contains all the attributes of the table. If you calculate the closure of `A` with respect to the given functional dependencies you will find:

```
A+ = {ABCD}
```

that does not contain the attribute `E`. So `A` is not a key, and `E` must be present in any key of `R`. And since:

```
AE+ = {ABCDE}
```

then `AE` is a key, and it is minimal (you cannot remove any attribute from it without losing the property of determining all the other attributes of the relation).